# How to add space(indent) before text except first line when print out. How to move this code to other class just call from main,

Tags: java, class

```
package com.Chall;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (String part : getParts("Indent space in every line ecept first printed line", 3, 5)) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}

private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize, int maxLine) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    int len = string.length();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
        parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
        count++;
        if (maxLine == count) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return parts;
}
}
```

Comment: if list.size > 0 then print it and iterate over the list from index 1.. simple.. what's exactly you need?

Comment: When result is printed all lines except the first line should be indented (they should start with a space character), 
but the second character in an indented line should not be another space (so that second space must not be included).

Comment: so "add a space if there is no space at beginning except for 1st line " ?

Answer (score 0):

for `(3,5)` you get:

```
Ind
 ent
 sp
 ace
 in
```

for `(7,5)` you get:

```
Indent
 space i
 n every
 line e
 cept fi
```

---

With this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printList(getParts("Indent space in every line ecept first printed line", 3, 5));
}

private static void printList(List<String> parts) {
    for (String part : parts) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}

private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize, int maxLine) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    int len = string.length();
    int count = 0;
    String indent = ""; //<------
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
        parts.add(indent + string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)).trim());
        count++;
        indent = " ";   //<-------------
        if (maxLine == count) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return parts;
}
```

use `trim()` to remove space, and then add one

Comment: Thanks for the trim(). something new to learn.

Now should be included this indent in nimber of letters(partitionSize),
when i change to 7 and 5 give me a 
[Indent]
[ space i]
[ n every]
[ line e]
[ cept fi]
  In every line a different number of letters?

Comment: Please edit you post and give some expecter output because it's unclear

Comment: Indent <br/>
_space_i <br/>
_n_every <br/>
_line_e <br/>
_cept_fi

Comment: @sefesffse I got this restult with 7,5 yes

Comment: @sefesffse so you may think about voteup/accept the answer, this is how a forum works ;)